# SQLite Android - Updating (adding up) existing value with new one

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android and i am trying to use these code to update an entry's value:

```
"Update " + TableIncomeCategory + " Set " + Income_Cat_currentAmount + " = " + "'" + Income_Cat_currentAmount + "'"
                        + "+" + "'"+tran.getAmount()+"'" + " where " + Income_category_name + " LIKE " + "'" + tran.getCategory() + "'");
```

I am trying to add up the current amount (`Income_Cat_currentAmount`) with the new value (`tran.getAmount()`) the code is running without crashing but every time I run it, the new value replaces the old one rather than adding up together. Can anyone tell me why and how to solve it?  Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the formatting.
The SQL command ends up like this:

```sql
Update IncomeCategoryTab
Set currentAmount = 'currentAmount'+'123'
where category_name LIKE 'some category'
```

This is wrong because you are appending one string to another.

You must not quote column names, and you should not quote values that are not strings:

```sql
Update IncomeCategoryTab
Set currentAmount = currentAmount + 123
where category_name LIKE 'some category';
```

In Java, you should use parameters for string values (like the category name) to avoid having to correctly quote them (which becomes more complex if they can contain quotes):

```java
db.execSQL("Update "+TableIncomeCategory+
           " Set "+Income_Cat_currentAmount+" = "+Income_Cat_currentAmount+" + "+tran.getAmount()+
           " where "+Income_category_name+" LIKE ?;",
           new Object[]{ tran.getCategory() });
```